# Rails: jQuery not defined after refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app and Jquery is loaded on the first loading of the app. However, if I refresh the page, then Jquery isn't loaded anymore:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require cocoon
// = require_tree .
```

My application layout file loads the javascript like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue moving `<%= yield :javascript %>` after the `javascript_include_tag`.